# Avoid cascade of serialization in Java Sound classes?

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

Currently I'm trying to send through a Socket an object which is a 'Message' class, which contains an AudioFormat and a Mixer that a second Java applications will use to configure itself.

```
public class Message implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

SerializableAudioFormat audioFormat;
Mixer mixer;

public Message(SerializableAudioFormat audioFormat, Mixer mixer) {
    this.audioFormat = audioFormat;
    this.mixer = mixer;
}

public SerializableAudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
    return this.audioFormat;
}

public Mixer getMixer() {
    return this.mixer;
    }

}
```

I had to serialize AudioFormat as by default it isn't, so I created the class that you can see in the constructor, 'SerializableAudioFormat'. The code of the class is the following one.

**SerializableAudioFormat class:**

```
public class SerializableAudioFormat implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

transient AudioFormat format;

public SerializableAudioFormat(AudioFormat format) {
    this.format = format;
}

public AudioFormat getAf() {
    return this.format;
}

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    out.defaultWriteObject();
    out.writeObject(new SerializableEncoding(format.getEncoding()));
    out.writeFloat(format.getSampleRate());
    out.writeInt(format.getSampleSizeInBits());
    out.writeInt(format.getChannels());
    out.writeInt(format.getFrameSize());
    out.writeFloat(format.getFrameRate());
    out.writeBoolean(format.isBigEndian());
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    in.defaultReadObject();
    format = new AudioFormat(((SerializableEncoding) in.readObject()).getEncoding(), in.readFloat(), in.readInt(),
            in.readInt(), in.readInt(), in.readFloat(), in.readBoolean());
    }

}
```

And as you can also see, the Encoding had to be serialized also because of the same reason. The class is the following one.

**SerializableEncoding class:**

```
public class SerializableEncoding implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    transient Encoding encoding;

    public SerializableEncoding(Encoding encoding) {
        this.encoding = encoding;
    }

    public Encoding getEncoding() {
        return this.encoding;
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.defaultWriteObject();
        out.writeObject(this);
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        in.defaultReadObject();
        encoding = ((SerializableEncoding) in.readObject()).getEncoding();
    }

}
```

The problem is that I started with an error that said...

Exception in thread "main" java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: ...

First with AudioFormat until I wrapped it, and then with AudioFormat.Encoding until I wrapped it also.

Now, my problem is with the interface Mixer as the error message that I'm getting is the following one.

**Exception in thread "main" java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice**

So my question is, is there any other workaround for this kind of scenario where you haven't developed the classes and most of them don't implement Serializable? Is it possible to avoid this 'mass serialization'?

Comment: 1.) Encoding may be serialized as String, using writeUTF(Encoding.toString()), no separated class required   2.) As AudioFormat does not have a default constructor, extending AudioFormat is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in your title:

```
out.writeObject(this);
```

The recursion is here. You're already doing that in the caller. Remove.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that solved the problem! But it seems that I can't get the value of the field to the other Java application as a NullPointerException pops up. Is there any other problem related to the serialization?

Comment: Too broad. There are any number of things you could have done wrong: but an NPE is an NPE and the solution is always the same.